# I write a log in project in python but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, logging

```
user_names = ['yasin' , 'abbas' , 'zahra']
passwords = ['1388' , '1234' , '2276']

deta = list(zip(user_names , passwords))

input_user = input("enter user name: ")
input_pass = input("enter password: ")
list_input_user = [input_user]
list_input_pass = [input_pass]
user_deta = list(zip(list_input_user,list_input_pass))

for check in deta :
    i += 1
    if i >= 1:
        check2 = f"[{check}]"
    if user_deta == check2 :
        print("Ok")
    else user_deta == check2 :
        print("NO")
    print(check2)
    print(user_deta)
```

This is my code but when I Run the project, back me **"NO".**
If you know the problem please help me.

Comment: this is not a valid syntax. `else` have no condition. did you mean `elif`? and if, so the condition have to be different otherwise it would make no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the syntax error, there is a cleaner way to check the user\pwd.

You can combining each user\pwd into a tuple then checking each tuple in the user list. A quicker way it to just use `in` to check if the entered user\pwd exists in the user list.

Try this code:

```
user_names = ['yasin' , 'abbas' , 'zahra']
passwords = ['1388' , '1234' , '2276']

deta = list(zip(user_names , passwords))   # [('yasin', '1388'), ('abbas', '1234'), ('zahra', '2276')]

input_user = input("enter user name: ")
input_pass = input("enter password: ")
user_deta = input_user,input_pass    # ('yasin','1388')

if user_deta in deta:
    print("Ok")
else:
    print("NO")
```